# Required CSP rules for Facebook login

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, content-security-policy

Which are the required rules to allow a Facebook login?

I currently allow these:

```
defaultSrc: ["'self'",
        '*.facebook.com',
        '*.akamaihd.net'],
        scriptSrc: ["'self'",
         '*.facebook.com',
         '*.akamaihd.net',
         "'unsafe-inline'",
         "'unsafe-eval'"],
        frameSrc: [
        "'self'",
        '*.facebook.com',
        '*.akamaihd.net',
        styleSrc: ["'self'",
         "'unsafe-inline'"],
        imgSrc: ["'self'",
        '*.akamaihd.net',
        '*.facebook.com']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using just

```
{
  'default-src': "'none'",
  'script-src': "'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' connect.facebook.net",
  'connect-src': "'self'",
  'img-src': "'self' www.facebook.com",
  'style-src': "'self' 'unsafe-inline'",
  'frame-src': "s-static.ak.facebook.com static.ak.facebook.com www.facebook.com",
}
```

but I'm not sure if there's anything missing.
I don't think you'll need to allow `*.akamaihd.net` since this is just the CDN Facebook uses, and it is not required for Facebook Login.

**Update:** as stated on the comments below, this solution defeats the purpose of CSP and it's definitely not recommended as it's insecure.

Comment: is there any way to get this working without adding `unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-eval`? those options can severely deteriorate the effectiveness of CSP

Comment: at the present moment, not that I'm aware :/

Comment: That's really bad, this needs to be addressed by Facebook, ` 'script-src':  'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'` defeat the very purpose of CSP.. did you end up finding a way?

Comment: I don't think so :/
but it has been some time since I have looked at it, so don't take my word for it.